# tesseract fails with returns value 1

Tags: php, exec, ocr, tesseract

Hi I am creating a small function for ocr for this purpose I installed Tesseract using reference (URL : http://hanzratech.in/2015/01/16/ocr-using-tesseract-on-ubuntu-14-04.html). On terminal when I run command `/usr/local/bin/tesseract /opt/lampp/htdocs/catcha1/text.png newfile -l eng` it generate a file /home/myusername/newfile.txt but when I run the same command using php it doesn't work .  My code is here

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $com = "/usr/local/bin/tesseract /opt/lampp/htdocs/catcha1/text.png newfile -l eng";
   $res = exec($com);
 ?>
```

Even I have given full permission  to tesseract still I can't debug the issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't make the least attempt to obtain diagnose information. You are not using exec's second and third argument and probably not even checking what `$res` contains. Capturing stderr would not be a bad idea either.

Comment: hi i have passed the two more variable in exec $output and $return_value then I got null for output and 1 for return value .

Comment: If stderr doesn't give any clue, it doesn't seem that tesseract return values are documented (or at least I couldn't find them).

Comment: is the way of giving paths  okay according to you ?

Comment: I can't say, I've never used tesseract. But if `newfile` is a path, it's probably easier it you make it absolute.

Comment: no newfile is the name of file that going to be generated  and it will generate a file of named newfile.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115720/discussion-between-vandy-and-alvaro-gonzalez).